# Нужно ли отделять запятой деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

*Управлять умным холодильником пользователь может(,) даже не находясь дома.*

Нужна ли запятая? Мне кажется, что нет, потому что деепричастный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым (без "не находясь дома" предложение теряет смысл). Но что-то закралось сомнение.

Понятно, что предложение вообще не очень удачно построено, но интересует именно запятая.

Comment: Я больше за отсутствие запятой в таких случаях, но у Розенталя в другом справочнике сказано, что запятая обычно ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое правило Розенталя про частицы (частицы "даже" там нет, но её можно туда добавить, потому что ситуация очень похожа):
Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы *только, лишь*, интонационно не обособляется от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но для сохранения единообразия рекомендуется отделять его запятой и в этом случае. Например:
*Они могли разговаривать, только крича во весь голос, и на расстоянии нескольких шагов теряли друг друга.

С угрозой реакции можно бороться, лишь добиваясь эффективного единства действия и целей всех демократических и антифашистских сил.

Избавиться от этого явления можно, только соблюдая вакуумную гигиену.

Понять это произведение можно, только учитывая условия его создания.

Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им.*

Потеря смысла в этих примерах сопоставима. Она не критична (структура не страдает).

Смысл этого правила больше в словах *может, могли, можно* и т.п. Они есть в каждом примере.